# How to Write aggregation query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to write a query that sums a field based on a condition like (**data**) in laravel,
but don't know how to write in better way, this is my query:

```
select currency,sum(total)
 from expenses 
 join currencies on currencies.cur_id = expenses.currency_id
 where(expenses.currency_id=1 and exp_date = '12-06-2016')
```

any help.

thanks

Comment: As I can see, This is the best query you can write to achieve what you have achieved. One join, and a where close. That's all you have used.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You might need to add a group by currency in there. Since you are using an aggregate function

Comment: Thanks all for the reply.